# set SD card image to ImageView?

Tags: android

I have an images in `SD card` i want to take image from `SD card` and set in the `ImageView`.please help me guys i have tried the below code.

**My Code:**

```
 sendImageFromFolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Uri uri=null;
                    ArrayList<Uri> arrayList=new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                    File pictues= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                    String[] listOfPictures=pictues.list();
                    for(String s:listOfPictures){
                        uri=Uri.parse("file://"+ pictues.toString() +"/"+s);
                        arrayList.add(uri);


                    }

                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;
                    Bitmap bmp;

                    try {
                        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(arrayList.get(0));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 File pictureFile = new File("Path to your image");
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
 mImage.setImage(bitmap);
```

Comment: what is pictureFile ??